# while trying to install Setup Oracle Java 9 as a Java Environment Variable, I ran into the an issue

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dpkg, oracle

I am very new to linux, as in three days into it and new to this forum, if I made have an error please let me know.

Here is the error I received after entering sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-set-default

```
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java9-set-default_9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
Full output -
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
cabextract chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
libavcodec-extra libhal1-flash libmspack0 libunshield0 oxideqt-codecs-extra
unshield xplayer-plugins-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
oracle-java9-set-default
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 3'540 B of archives.
After this operation, 16.4 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty/main amd64  oracle-java9-set-default all 9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0 [3'540 B]
Fetched 3'540 B in 1s (2'061 B/s)                   
Selecting previously unselected package oracle-java9-set-default.
(Reading database ... 235497 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../oracle-java9-set-default_9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
Unpacking oracle-java9-set-default (9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java9-set-default_9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh', which is also in package oracle-java8-set-default 8u101+8u101arm-1~webupd8~2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java9-set-default_9b126+9b126arm-1~webupd8~0_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running these commands before installing the package again.

This will remove those unused packages.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will update and upgrade the packages.

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you for responding - ok I did this - What should I do next - do i need to remove the install? I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What output are you getting now? and what version of ubuntu??

Comment: oh it looks like that worked, thank you so much my friend

Comment: Please up vote and mark it as solved :)!

Comment: sorry, how do i mark solved

Comment: there should be somewhere by my answer where you can approve it with a checkmark

Comment: found it, thank you again, sorry for the noob questions